# What is best practice make infinite loop in Kotlin coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My code is like this.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
            while (true) { // do something.. } 
}
```

It's somewhat awkward. :(

Is this right way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use `GlobalScope` for creating infinite loops . Since one of your tag mentions android , assuming you are writing program for the same , it is highly recommended that you use `LifycycleScope` / `ViewModelScope` when you are in `Fragment-Activity` / `ViewModel` respectively .

It is easy to accidentally create resource or memory leaks when `GlobalScope` is used. But since these scopes(lifecycleScope / viewModelScope) are `lifecycle-aware` , they will get automatically cancelled when the particular class(fragment/viewModel) is killed . Either you use one of the prebuilt-scope or create your own scope handling the lifecycle with `viewLifecycleScope` instead of using the GlobalScope for creating an infinite loop .
You can make use of viewModelScope in the following way :

```
fun runForever() {
    // start a new coroutine in the ViewModel
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // cancelled when the ViewModel is cleared
        while(true) {
            delay(1_000)
            // do something every second
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx! @Katunesh Palekar  Is it same way in foreground service not activity?

Comment: Yes , you need to create your own scope with the help of `viewLifecycleScope` , and make sure it follows the required measurements.